# Quick Question: Use the default value of the scipy.optimize.minimize tol parameter

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I was looking through the documentation of `scipy.optimize.minimize` for the **default value of the parameter `tol`**, but [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) the only description of the parameter is

> Tolerance for termination. For detailed control, use solver-specific options.

I need a way to assign a default value to the parameter, since I want the user to chose whether or not he would like to set a custom tolerance. If there should not be a tolerance set, I don't know what to put into the variable. Also, it cannot be method-specific, since the method can also be chosen by the user.
I would save a lot of time if I knew the default value, since there are a lot of different minimize calls -> if statements would make the code very ugly and quite a bit longer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L573) how the `tol` parameter is handled in minimize. The default value is method specific. For example for Nelder-Mead they are `xatol=1e-4, fatol=1e-4`. You should check out all the methods [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L606). (They are named as `_minimize_methodname`.) I don't think there is a way to set a global `tol`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I hoped there might be a way to set tol to like None or something so that minimize would pick the method specific one. But yeah I am just going to set the tolerance to like 0.0001 or something the like for all methods. Thanks! :D